# How can a virtual machine scale set agent run interactive UI tests in an elevated process?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-vm-scale-set

When configuring the scale set agent, I can check the box to configure the VMs to run interactive tests:

[image: checkbox]

[According to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/scale-set-agents?view=azure-devops#create-the-scale-set-agent-pool), this runs in an unelevated session. How can I have my interactive UI tests run elevated?

Comment: Turn off UAC and add the user running the agent to the local administrator group.

Answer (score 0):

The standard GitHub Actions and Azure Pipelines agents do the following to achieve this:

- [Turn off User Account control (UAC)](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/211da2488f82dff735b407282bf312b4d19049c0/images/windows/scripts/build/Configure-BaseImage.ps1#L28-L31).
- It sets up the user as a member of the Local Administrators group.

Comment: [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/scale-set-agents?view=azure-devops#create-the-scale-set-agent-pool) say it's already a member of the administrators group. Do I turn off UAC in a custom script extension? I'm concerned this won't get executed before the azure devops extension.

Comment: If the Custom Script Extension is installed, it's executed before the Azure Pipelines Agent extension. See the detailed info from [Lifecycle of a Scale Set Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/scale-set-agents?view=azure-devops#how-azure-pipelines-manages-the-scale-set:~:text=If%20the%20Custom%20Script%20Extension%20is%20installed%2C%20it%27s%20executed%20before%20the%20Azure%20Pipelines%20Agent%20extension.).

Comment: Or make it part of the provisioning of the VM Image.

Comment: @jessehouwing From my tests, this doesn't seem to work. I turn off UAC by setting the `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System` registry value to 0. I then add a user called "Bob" and assign him to the Administrators group.

When I log in as Admin, all processes automatically run elevated. However when I log in as bob, they are not elevated unless I right click and select "run as administrator". 

The AzDevops account seems runs into this issue and runs processes unelevated.